# MVC programming best practise

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Team,
          I am new to MVC and need some suggestion, well  I have come across a situation where in I have to put multiple objects on a same view e.g. display employee, dept, etc details on same page for this I have appropriate models and since single model object is passed from controller to view  I have created a view model which contain instance of the all the model  my first query is

1. Below viewmodel EmpVM - Is this the right approach for passing object from controller to view this class will be instantiated in controller of particular view.
2. In case I have multiple entries of a entity i.e. address(shipping and billing) in address table is it fine to declare two instance of object in viewmodel or declare a single list and iterate in view to populeate one in grid and another in controls.

**

```
public class EmpVM
{    
        List<Address> multiAddObj{get;set}
        Address singAddobj{get;set;}
}
```

**

Any suggestion/help on this will be of gr8 help.

Thanks in advance.
HSR.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is perfectly OK to have a ViewModel object which encapsulates multiple model objects. You did right.
2. It depends on what's logically "correct" to your applications. For some purposes you should create an IEnumerable object and iterate it in the view, while in other cases it would make more sense to simply have to model objects in the ViewModel.